# Manually install Google USB drivers

Tags: usb, drivers, installation, android

My SDK and AVD manager is unable to access the Google USB drivers. I believe this is a firewall issue and a proxy could work, however, I would like to avoid this route if possible.

Is there a way I can manually download and install the Google USB driver pacakage?

Comment: I feel this question belongs more over here: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If the driver doesn't work for you, [follow these instructions](https://sites.google.com/site/mid7012cobykyros/home/installing-adb-andriod-debug-bridge):

> 1. Using the "SDK Manager" that came with the Andriod SDK, you can download the Google USB Driver package.
> 2. Open the file "android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\andriod_winusb.inf" in note pad
>      or some other text editor.
> 3. Find the line that reads "[Google.NTx86]"
> 4. Add the following 2 lines right under "[Google.NTx86]"
>
>    ```
>    %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_DEED
>    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_DEED&MI_01
>    ```
> 5. Find the line that reads "[Google.NTamd64]"
> 6. Add the following 2 lines right under [Google.NTamd64]
>
>    ```
>    %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_DEED
>    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_DEED&MI_01
>    ```
> 7. Turn USB debugging on in tablet
> 8. Connect the tablet
> 9. Point to inf file

Comment: These instructions would work only for a device with those specific USB IDs. As @Duke's answer says, you should look on Device Manager for your device specific IDs and replace them in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

1. Locate `android_winusb.inf` file and open it for editing.
2. Add below `[Google.NTx86]` and `[Google.NTamd64]` following lines (same under both):

   ```
   %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010
   %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&MI_01
   ```

Important: Replace `VID_2207` and `PID_0010` with numbers from device information. Open Device Manager, right-click on your device and click on Properties, then Details.
Check several properties from the dropdown box to find out your VID and PID.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try running the program as Administrator. Even I didn't see the sense in that at first as I was in an Administrator account, but there is a difference in available options when you right click on the "SDK Manager.exe" and then "Run as Administrator" as opposed to just double-clicking. Hope it works.